# Meteor is refreshing after client is modified (even when image is created in public)

Tags: meteor

Is there a way to control the Meteor's auto refreshing when client was modified ? I have a method which is creating an image in the public/ directory and every time when a image was created the App on localhost is reloading which is a bit disturbing.

After creating an image this message showed up:

```
=> Client modified -- refreshing
```

To test I've just copy an image to the public/ directory and the server restarted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a normal behavior. It is because you are running you meteor application in development mode.

Check if this is the case as shown here: [How a meteor application knows if it's running on development, test or production environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11183424/how-a-meteor-application-knows-if-its-running-on-development-test-or-productio)

You need to change it in your application global settings, or wait until you deploy it (and set it to `production`).

Comment: So there is no way for me to control this ? e.g.: Just refresh when its NOT because of a new file in public/ directory ?

Comment: As far as I know, it's all or nothing. You can get rid of that by using a dedicated assets server such as nginx or use gridFS/CollectionFS to store your files, but it is just a time consuming work-around, especially if you are satisfied by the (other) `public` folder features (available for every-one, built-in URLs, etc.)

Comment: Alright. Thanks for this information. Its a bit of disturbing but I have to live with it until I am going to production. :)